# Webpack Dev Server Cannot Get / 404 Error

Tags: javascript, webpack, http-status-code-404, webpack-dev-server

I installed webpack dev server in order to launch my project. Readiing the documentation, I managed to write a config for a dev server.

My working tree looks like this:

```
dist
  pokemon.js
  pokemon.html

src
  index.js
  pokemon.html

webpack.config.js
```

This is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',

    entry: {
        pokemon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        //NOTE: Используем хеширование https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /.html$/,
                loader: "html-loader"
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Struggling with Webpack',
            filename: 'pokemon.html',
            template: 'src/pokemon.html'
        })
    ],

    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: './dist',
        },
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }
}
```

After running `webpack serve` Im getting 'Cannot GET/' error, but visiting `http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server` I can see my files from ./dist directory and able to open them in a browser.

I tried to find a solution from different question on StackOverflow, but I did not get any working solution. I think I might be loosing some important detail about the config.